# Error al cambiar tamaño de Sketchpad

Tags: javascript

Resulta que estoy haciendo un pequeño sketchpad simple (uno de los ejercicios de The Odin Project) y al pulsar el boton para cambiar el tamaño del board resulta que los divs se van encogiendo y el click funciona aleatoriamente, si lo cambio varias veces va encogiendo aun mas... Alguna solución?

Imagino que el error ha de estar en `getBoard()`, quizás se están stackeando, pero no se me ocurre una solucion ahora mismo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" lang="en">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Sketchpad!</title>
    <h1>Sketchpad!</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-size">
            <button class="btn btn-warning get-size">Select a size</button>
        </div>
        <div class="click-message-on">Click enabled, you can paint! ✔️</div>
        <div class="click-message-off"></div>
        <div class="error-message"></div>
        <div class="board"></div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button data-color="black" class="btn btn-dark">Black</button>
            <button data-color="red" class="btn btn-danger">Red</button>
            <button data-color="blue" class="btn btn-primary">Blue</button>
            <button data-color="random" class="btn btn-success">Random</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary clear space">Clear</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</head>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container-size {
    display: flex;
}

.board {
    display: grid;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid orangered;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.sq {
    background: rgb(235, 135, 99);
    border: thin solid rgb(230, 102, 55);
}

.space {
    margin-left: 3em;
}

.get-size {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.click-message-on, .click-message-off {
    color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

.click-message-off {
    color: red
}

.error-message {
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: brown;
}
```

JS:

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-color]');
let buttonSize = document.querySelector('.get-size');
let buttonClear = document.querySelector('.clear');
let color = 'black';
let click = true;
let clickMessage = document.querySelector('.click-message-on');
let clickMessageOff = document.querySelector('.click-message-off');
let errorMessage = document.querySelector('.error-message');

buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function changeColor(){
        let colorSelection = button.dataset.color;
        color = colorSelection;
    })
})

buttonSize.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let size = getSize();
    getBoard(size, size);
});

buttonClear.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.sq');
    squares.forEach((square) => {
        square.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(235, 135, 99)';
    })
})

function getBoard(cols, rows) {
    let board = document.querySelector('.board');
    board.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${cols}, 1fr)`
    board.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${rows}, 1fr)`
    let size = cols * rows;
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        let fill = document.createElement('div');
        fill.className = 'sq';
        fill.addEventListener('mouseover', getColor);
        board.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', fill);
    }
    board.addEventListener('click', function() {
        click = !click;
        if (click) {
            clickMessage.textContent = 'Click enabled, you can paint! ✔️';
            clickMessageOff.textContent = '';
        } else {
            clickMessageOff.textContent = 'Click disabled, you can\'t paint! ❌';
            clickMessage.textContent = '';
        }
    })
}

function getColor() {
    if (click) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = color;
        if (color === 'random') {
        this.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${Math.random() * 360}, 100%, 50%)`;
        }
    }
}

function getSize() {
    let input = prompt('Select a size');
    input = parseFloat(input);
    if (input <= 0) {
        errorMessage.textContent = 'Negative numbers are not valid!';
    } else if (input > 64) {
        errorMessage.textContent = 'Enter a number between 1 and 64';
    } else if (input !== Number(input)) {
        errorMessage.textContent = 'Only numbers allowed';
    } else {
        return input;
    }
}

getBoard(32, 32);
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: No dejes links, agrega el código y formatéalo como tal ya que no es muy extenso tranquilamente puedes agregarlo como parte de la pregunta

Comment: Lo he intentado pero me dice que la pregunta es mayormente codigo, agrego solo el JS?

Comment: Listo ya lo agregue